# For what x can we solve $1,2,3,x=5$

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

This is a variation on the formation of numbers theme.

> Given $1, 2, 3, x$ in order, and the operations plus, minus, times, divide, and brackets, what single digits can x NOT be?

i.e. find a solution for $x$ from $0$ to $9$, or prove there is no solution.

For example if $x=4$ we have:

> $ (1+2)\times3-4=5$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible for x = {0-9}.

> $X=0: \;\;1 \times 2 + 3 + 0 = 5$
>  $X=1: \;\;1 \times 2 \times3 - 1 = 5$
>  $X=2: \;\;1 + 2 \times 3 - 2 = 5$
>  $X=3: \;\;1 - 2 + 3 + 3 = 5$
>  $X=4: \;\;(1 + 2) \times 3 - 4 = 5$
>  $X=5: \;\;(1 + 2) / 3 \times 5 = 5$
>  $X=6: \;\;1 + 2 / 3 \times 6 = 5$
>  $X=7: \;\;1 / 2 \times (3 + 7) = 5$
>  $X=8: \;\;(1 - 2) \times 3 + 8 = 5$
>  $X=9: \;\;1 - 2 - 3 + 9 = 5$

Comment: they have to be in order

Comment: and done! Here you go!

Comment: I don't think negation is allowed. A subtraction (minus) operation requires two operands.

Comment: Not sure if it was required, but answer has since been fixed to remove negation.

Comment: You don't need the brackets in lines X=1 and X=2.

Comment: Fixed. Was originally there because I used them when playing around with the numbers

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions:

> $X=1:\;\;1+2+3-1=5$
>  $X=1:\;\;(1\times2+3)\times1=5$
>  $X=1:\;\;1\times2+3\times1=5$